# i wanted to know the nontrivial connected graph G with the following properties.

Tags: graph-theory

Give an example of a nontrivial connected graph G with the properties that (1) every bridge of G is adjacent to an edge that is not a bridge, (2) every edge of G that is not a bridge is adjacent to a bridge, (3) G contains two nonadjacent bridges and (4) every two edges of G that are not bridges are adjacent.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The [Bull graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bull_graph) is such an example.